# Negation of multiple RewriteCond in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ip

I want to redirect all but my country IPs to a subfolder. This is what I came up with.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond expr "-R '217.197.32.0/20'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "-R '217.197.144.0/20'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "-R '217.198.112.0/20'"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfolder/$1 [R,L]
```

(It's just the last 3 lines of the IP list.)

It does redirect, but not correctly. If you're a foreigner you stay in root, but if your IP matches you get redirected to a subfolder.

Is there a way to negate it? I tried `RewriteCond expr "! -R '217.197.32.0/20'" [OR]` adding the `!` to every `RewriteCond` line but no luck either.

Comment: It might be easiest, if you just inserted a RewriteRule after your IP-checking conditions, that doesn’t do any substitution (`-` as the “target”), and uses the [`S` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) to skip the next rule. That way, you don’t need to negate your IP matching logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried `RewriteCond expr "! -R '217.197.32.0/20'" [OR]` adding the `!` to every RewriteCond line but no luck either.

If you negate the condition then you would also need to remove the `OR` flag (to make it an implicit AND) in order to change the logic. (Otherwise the conditions will always be successful... !A or !B or !C is always true)

You don't need the condition that checks against the URL-path - this should be incorporated into the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead. (Or move this condition to the top.)

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond expr "! -R '217.197.32.0/20'"
RewriteCond expr "! -R '217.197.144.0/20'"
RewriteCond expr "! -R '217.198.112.0/20'"
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ http://example.com/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```